# Get all children with all parents in SQL tree structure with SQLite

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have the following database model:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS account (
    name VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY,
    parent INTEGER REFERENCES account(name) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE 
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS permission (
    name VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS account_permission (
    account VARCHAR NOT NULL REFERENCES account(name) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    permission VARCHAR NOT NULL REFERENCES permission(name) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);

DELETE FROM account;
DELETE FROM permission;
DELETE FROM account_permission;

INSERT INTO account(name) VALUES('a1');
INSERT INTO account(name) VALUES('a2');
INSERT INTO account(name, parent) VALUES('a3', 'a1');

INSERT INTO permission(name) VALUES('dummy');
INSERT INTO permission(name) VALUES('edit');
INSERT INTO permission(name) VALUES('delete');

INSERT INTO account_permission(account, permission) VALUES('a1', 'dummy');
INSERT INTO account_permission(account, permission) VALUES('a2', 'edit');
INSERT INTO account_permission(account, permission) VALUES('a3',  'delete');
```

What I want is a query which returns all accounts which have a permission and their permissions inherited from the parent account. In this case I expect a result like this:

account  | permission
a1       | dummy
a2       | edit
a3       | dummy
a3       | delete

a1 and a2 is nothing special but I have no idea how to write the recursive query to include a3 with all parent permissions and its own permission. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How many levels of the parents? Can a3 also be a parent let say for a4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

P.s.
You should redesign the tables.
Account should have an ID and a NAME.
Permission should have an ID and a NAME.
Tables should be connected by IDs.

---

The iterative query returns tuples of accounts and ancestors (including self)

```
+---------+----------+
| account | ancestor |
+---------+----------+
| a1      | a1       |
+---------+----------+
| a2      | a2       |
+---------+----------+
| a3      | a1       |
+---------+----------+
| a3      | a3       |
+---------+----------+
```

The rest of the query is for matching each account`s ancestor with its permissions and removing redundancies.

---

```
with        t 
            as
            (
                select      name     as account   
                           ,name     as ancestor

                from        account

             -- where       name = ... /* for a specific account */      

                union all

                select      t.account
                           ,a.parent    as ancestor

                from                t   
                            join    account as a
                            on      a.name = t.ancestor
                where       a.parent is not null
            )

select      distinct

            t.account
           ,ap.permission

from                    t
            join        account_permission  as ap
            on          ap.account  = t.ancestor

order by    t.account
           ,ap.permission     
;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. This was an example to keep it simple without any ID fields. I have a question about the first select. Is it neccessary to get all accounts? That results in a huge overhead when there are a lot of them. The result is expected to be redundant because I need a table with all permissions for a single account including the parent permission.

Comment: (1) We can simplify things but still keep on good design principles. Keeping the IDs would be better. `permission` for instance has no use in this example. (2) Let's take a scenario where an account have 7 ancestors and each of them have 2 unique privileges (that no one else has). We would expect for 14 records for this account, 2 per ancestor. The inner query traverse up the tree and connect the account to its 7 ancestors. This will yields 7 rows. The outer query joins the ancestors to their permissions - 7*2=14

Comment: You can put a WHERE filter on the first SELECT in the CTE.

Comment: @CL., please notice that I'm going "bottom-up" from each account and not "top-bottom" as in the "classic" cte

Comment: Yes, you can start with the accounts you're actually interested in. (This is in response to the question if it is necessary to get all accounts.)

Comment: @CL. thanks, got in now. I'll update the answer in a minute

Comment: I tried this query but it results in a loop which never returns

Comment: @Gustavo, it works for your example. If you are in loop with your real data it means your real data has cycles.

Comment: @Gustavo - P.s. I hope you have switched to IDs.

Comment: Of course I did. The endless loop was my fault. I uses sqlfiddle with postgresql as database. Sqlite works.

Answer (score 0):

You will need one more query, which fetch parent permission and that can be merged with union. Here it is

```
select * from  account_permission 
union 
select  a.name, ap.permission  from account_permission  ap,  account a where        a.parent = ap.account
```